# Exception in java ME

Tags: java, android

I want to test that an edit text box is not empty before a user clicks on the button to get a result, I want the application to inform the user that the particular textbox cannot be empty and return back to the application instead of throwing an exception. I tried using the try and catch statement but the catch is always having an error. please help

```
               public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                EditText locName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
                String textName = locName.getText().toString();

                if (textName != null){
                    getAddress();
                }else if (textName == null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter a destination address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

        }
```

Comment: What kind of exception did you get? Why the question has "java me" instead of "Android"

Comment: logcat output would be useful. Suggesting to add checks for null for locName and locName.getText() (before call of toString()).

Answer (score 0):

After this: `String textName = locName.getText().toString();` you could make sure that the `.length` property is not equal to zero. If it is, then display the notification and exit from the event handler through the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the Exception and then in the catch section provide the User with the Message and dont throw the Exception again.

Answer (score 0):

try like this....

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText locName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);

            if (locName.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                getAddress();
            }
            else if(locName.getText().toString().length() == 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter a destination address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, ur method worked though i had to use locName instead of textName

Answer (score 0):

use this to validate the `EditText`

```
if(sUserName.trim().length()==0 || sPassword.trim().length()==0){
        MsgBox(ctx,"Please enter Login credentials to activate !");
        return;
    }
```